# make text appear above border using css

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was any way to put the Success text above the red border on the top?

[image]

I am using it with pure css but cant seem to get it to work

```
form:before {
    content: "SUCCESS";
    color:red;
    position:absolute;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Here is a fiddle:

```css
.success {
    outline:2px solid green;
}
.success:before {
    content:"SUCCESS";
    color:green;
    top:-20px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="success">Hello</div>
```

Comment: add a JSFiddle, the chances for an full and detailed answer will be higher.

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
form:before {
        content: "SUCCESS";
        color:red;
        position:absolute;
        top:-20px;
        left:0px;

    }
```

Comment: A short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.

Comment: @Jeeped agree with you , but sometimes the answer is too simple to consider a useless paragraph just to make it look as a complicated answer.

Comment: @Jeeped im just here to help people , once they find their answer , i may even delete my answer , because after all this is not a generic issue , it is usually someone seeking help just because they are beginners.

Comment: @Jeeped again im totally agreed with you , but this question is not the case at all :D

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code on JSFiddle and provided it here also, hope that gives you the rough idea: https://jsfiddle.net/esLcd54a/24/

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.padding
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.success
{
    outline: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.success:before
{
    content:"SUCCESS";
    color:green;
    position:absolute;
    top:-30px;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="success">Hello</div>
```

Comment: it seems to just get cut off now :(. i wonder if it is even possible to do what Im asking

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but please provide a working example and I'll have a go if you want

Comment: Is there any reason you need to do this with the before pseudo-element rather than another element?